# There's sidebar information below my footer?

Tags: php, wordpress, footer, sidebar

There's this fixed sidebar info permanently beneath my footer. I created a child theme in Wordpress but didn't touch any of the files yet. I did add a footer from Envato elements, then clicked around the sidebar widgets, but right now there are no sidebar widgets saved so I'm not sure why this text is permanently stuck to my footer.

[image: Photo of my sidebar info stuck beneath footer]

```
    <?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the footer.
 *
 * @package OceanWP WordPress theme
 */ ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->

        <?php do_action( 'ocean_after_main' ); ?>

        <?php do_action( 'ocean_before_footer' ); ?>

        <?php
        // Elementor `footer` location
        if ( ! function_exists( 'elementor_theme_do_location' ) || ! elementor_theme_do_location( 'footer' ) ) { ?>

            <?php do_action( 'ocean_footer' ); ?>

        <?php } ?>

        <?php do_action( 'ocean_after_footer' ); ?>

    </div><!-- #wrap -->

    <?php do_action( 'ocean_after_wrap' ); ?>

</div><!-- #outer-wrap -->

<?php do_action( 'ocean_after_outer_wrap' ); ?>

<?php
// If is not sticky footer
if ( ! class_exists( 'Ocean_Sticky_Footer' ) ) {
    get_template_part( 'partials/scroll-top' );
} ?>

<?php
// Search overlay style
if ( 'overlay' == oceanwp_menu_search_style() ) {
    get_template_part( 'partials/header/search-overlay' );
} ?>

<?php
// If sidebar mobile menu style
if ( 'sidebar' == oceanwp_mobile_menu_style() ) {

    // Mobile panel close button
    if ( get_theme_mod( 'ocean_mobile_menu_close_btn', true ) ) {
        get_template_part( 'partials/mobile/mobile-sidr-close' );
    } ?>

    <?php
    // Mobile Menu (if defined)
    get_template_part( 'partials/mobile/mobile-nav' ); ?>

    <?php
    // Mobile search form
    if ( get_theme_mod( 'ocean_mobile_menu_search', true ) ) {
        get_template_part( 'partials/mobile/mobile-search' );
    }

} ?>

<?php
// If full screen mobile menu style
if ( 'fullscreen' == oceanwp_mobile_menu_style() ) {
    get_template_part( 'partials/mobile/mobile-fullscreen' );
} ?>

<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the code inside your footer.php ? This is the ace to have a look at to find out, what is inserted inside your footer.

Comment: I added the footer.php in my original post! Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Looks like you are displaying a sidebar inside of your footer. There is an if condition in your code which checks `if ('sidebar ...'` . Try to delete the whole if clause (but keep a copy), does it help? If not, I don't know what the actions are doing...maybe you got a sidebar element in your footer placed within a visual builder. Do you know something about the `<?php do_action( 'ocean_footer' ); ?>` and what ocean_footer is?

Answer (score 0):

I just had to make my footer 100% and it hid those sidebar lines.